# Convert struct of structs to array of structs pulling struct field name inside

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the following schema:

```
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
```

into this:

```
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Really just trying to get the struct key and convert it into a string and add it into a column. The `b`/`c` structs in the dataset are numerous, so will need some wildcard to convert them.

I'm using Spark 3.2.1.

The data is generated from JSON, so is read like this:

```py
df = spark.read.json(json_file)
```

Comment: `selectExpr('array(a.*) as a')` should work in your case

Comment: Works alright converting the struct to an array but didn't help with moving the struct key into a k:v pair in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this approach, as often we need to retain other columns which are present in the original dataframe. This method doesn't remove other columns.

```py
dtype = df.schema['a'].dataType[0].dataType.simpleString()
df = df.withColumn('a', F.map_values(F.transform_values(
    F.from_json(F.to_json("a"), f'map<string,{dtype}>'), 
    lambda k, v: v.withField('struct_key', k)
)))
```

`df.schema['a'].dataType[0].dataType.simpleString()` navigates to the inner struct and extracts its schema in DDL format.
`F.from_json(F.to_json("a"), f'map<string,{dtype}>')` converts the inner *struct* into *map*. The field name of the struct becomes map's key, while the struct itself becomes map's value. This conversion is useful, because it makes it easier to access the field name.
`F.transform_values(..., lambda k, v: v.withField('struct_key', k))` adds the map's key into map's value (i.e. into the struct).
`F.map_values()` extracts the values of the map, thus making an array of structs.

---

Test input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(9, ((1.1, [], '', True),(2.2, [], '', True),),)],
    'x int, a struct<b:struct<one:double,two:array<string>,three:string,four:boolean>,c:struct<one:double,two:array<string>,three:string,four:boolean>>')

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+--------------------------------------+
# |x  |a                                     |
# +---+--------------------------------------+
# |9  |{{1.1, [], , true}, {2.2, [], , true}}|
# +---+--------------------------------------+
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- x: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- c: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Result:

```py
dtype = df.schema['a'].dataType[0].dataType.simpleString()
df = df.withColumn('a', F.map_values(F.transform_values(
    F.from_json(F.to_json("a"), f'map<string,{dtype}>'), 
    lambda k, v: v.withField('struct_key', k)
)))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+--------------------------------------------+
# |x  |a                                           |
# +---+--------------------------------------------+
# |9  |[{1.1, [], , true, b}, {2.2, [], , true, c}]|
# +---+--------------------------------------------+
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- x: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- a: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- one: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- three: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- four: boolean (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Yeah, had a heap of existing columns I needed to keep.
This worked like a charm, thanks a heap.
Ended up manually specifying the dtype so I could convert a double to a string.
`dtype = 'struct<one:string,two:array<string>,three:string,four:boolean>'`

Answer (score 0):

here's an approach where you first add the `struct_key` within the inner structs and then create an array using them.

```py
# input
data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([(((1, 2), (3, 4)), 'foo', 'bar')], 
                                 'a struct<b: struct<foo: int, bar: int>, c: struct<foo: int, bar: int>>, col2 string, col3 string'
                                 )

# +----------------+----+----+
# |               a|col2|col3|
# +----------------+----+----+
# |{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}| foo| bar|
# +----------------+----+----+

# root
#  |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- bar: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- c: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- bar: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col3: string (nullable = true)

# processing
data_sdf. \
    selectExpr('a.*', *[c for c in data_sdf.columns if c not in ['a']]). \
    selectExpr(*['struct("{0}" as struct_key, {0}.*) as {0}'.format(c) for c in data_sdf.selectExpr('a.*').columns],
               *[c for c in data_sdf.columns if c not in ['a']]
               ). \
    withColumn('a', func.array(*data_sdf.selectExpr('a.*').columns)). \
    drop(*data_sdf.selectExpr('a.*').columns). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+----+----------------------+
# |col2|col3|a                     |
# +----+----+----------------------+
# |foo |bar |[{b, 1, 2}, {c, 3, 4}]|
# +----+----+----------------------+

# root
#  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- a: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- bar: integer (nullable = true)
```