# Transform and filter array of structs with parent struct field name

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, type-conversion

I am trying to do one more step further than this StackOverflow post ([Convert struct of structs to array of structs pulling struct field name inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299990/convert-struct-of-structs-to-array-of-structs-pulling-struct-field-name-inside)) where I need to pull the struct field name, filter each struct array based on a condition of role values and transform each struct element into a new struct with the extracted struct field name.

Input:

```
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- two: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
```

```
{
    "a": [{
            "two": [{
                "name": "person1"
                "role": "role1"
            },
            {
                "name": "person2"
                "role": "role1"
            },
            {
                "name": "person3"
                "role": "role2"
            }],
            "struct_key": "test1"
        },
        {
            "two": [{
                "name": "person4"
                "role": "role1"
            },
            {
                "name": "person5"
                "role": "role1"
            },
            {
                "name": "person6"
                "role": "role2"
            }],
            "struct_key": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
input ={
    "a": [{
            "two": [{
                    "name": "person1",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person2",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person3",
                    "role": "role2"
                }
            ],
            "struct_key": "test1"
        },
        {
            "two": [{
                    "name": "person4",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person5",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person6",
                    "role": "role2"
                }
            ],
            "struct_key": "test2"
        }
    ]
}

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([input]))
print(df.selectExpr('inline(a)').schema)
```

Expected output after filtering (for roles) and new struct transformation:

```
 |-- role_output: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

```
{
    role1_output: [
        {
            "struct_key": "test1",
            "name": "person1"
        }, 
        {
            "struct_key": "test1",
            "name": "person2"
        },
        {
            "struct_key": "test2",
            "name": "person4"
        },
        {
            "struct_key": "test2",
            "name": "person5"
        }
    ]
}

{
    role2_output: [
        {
            "struct_key": "test1",
            "name": "person3"
        }, 
        {
            "struct_key": "test2",
            "name": "person6"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried the struct to map type conversion from that StackOverflow post answer but cannot figure out how to combine the extracted `struct_key` with another array of struct field values and create a new struct as I start transforming the array element, I lose the `struct_key` field value. Any advice?

Comment: share the  schema  with data in Spark format . I may have solution for you

Comment: Added in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import array
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

input ={
    "a": [{
            "two": [{
                    "name": "person1",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person2",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person3",
                    "role": "role2"
                }
            ],
            "struct_key": "test1"
        },
        {
            "two": [{
                    "name": "person4",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person5",
                    "role": "role1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "person6",
                    "role": "role2"
                }
            ],
            "struct_key": "test2"
        }
    ]
}

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([input])).selectExpr('inline(a)').select('struct_key', explode('two')).groupBy('col.role').agg(collect_list(struct('col.name','struct_key')))
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
```

Gives you:

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|role |collect_list(struct(col.name, struct_key))                              |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|role2|[{person3, test1}, {person6, test2}]                                    |
|role1|[{person1, test1}, {person2, test1}, {person4, test2}, {person5, test2}]|
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_list(struct(col.name, struct_key)): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am running into this exception. Aren't you getting the same?

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'struct(`col`.`name`, `struct_key`)' due to data type mismatch: Only foldable string expressions are allowed to appear at odd position, got: NamePlaceholder;

Comment: No errors on my side. Spark 3.4.0, Python 3.9.6